# How to use AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor()

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an Asynctask and I want in the onPostExecute of that AsyncTask to execute another Asynctask.

my question is how can I use AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor() in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate class of `AsyncTask` and execute like

```
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    else
        task.execute();
```

task is an `Object` of `AsyncTask`

Comment: should i use that code in opstexecute of the first asynctask?

Comment: @LetsamrIt Yes why not?

Answer (score 0):

```
AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

Comment: should i use that code in opstexecute of the first asynctask